# different height masonry thumbnail using isotope

Tags: jquery

I just made a masonry thumbnail using isotope.
when it loaded, auto height doesn't work.
but when window resizing, it works.

Please give me some solution!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wcodavid/YdzS4/1/ JS FIDDLE

Comment: you may have to trigger the masonary refresh once all the images are loaded

Comment: I searched many articles, I don't understand TRIGGER :(

Comment: Have you tried to add this to you isotope options `resizesContainer : true` ?

Comment: Otherwise you need to set the height of the container in your css file.

Comment: @DavidStrada where I put this code in my jquery? and height of container is auto because of height of elements.

Comment: look my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

On your fiddle you need to have this 
`isotope = function () { 
    $container.isotope({ 
    resizable: false,
    resizesContainer : true, 
    itemSelector: '.item', 
    masonry: { 
         columnWidth: colWidth(), 
         gutterWidth: 4 
    } }); 
};`

Comment: Also you haven't included the basic styling that isotope requires.

Comment: My suggestion go to the docs and check them out, download the example and see how it works, this is really easy, you shouldn't be having this kind of problems.

Comment: Check the docs dude, [link](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/introduction.html#getting_started)